# Inject unique classNames with Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver

The page I'm testing uses very few id's. All of my locators are these long xpaths. I'm wondering, would there be any advantages or disadvantages if I first execute some javascript to inject unique classNames for every element, and and then just locate by className?

EDIT
I am already using the page object model.

My question is simply, are there any advantages to locating an element by className eg `"uniqueClass01"` rather than by an xpath such as 
`"/html/body/div[13]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[7]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[6]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/a"`

I have added unique classes to each element using the jsExecutor - that was easy. I'm just wondering if it's better to do it this way, or use xpaths like above.

Comment: Why can you not just give them actual ID's in the page markup? Why bother hacking it with Javascript when, if you have access to the development source, you can give it a proper ID there? I'm not sure why you need to go to such lengths.

Comment: @Arran, I am not the developer of the page. I am only testing it.

Comment: @Dingredient: The best thing to do is to add IDs properly, if that's not desirable (e.g for ExtJs), then you might add class names to the source. Injecting class names sounds difficult for me, say for example, you want to inject a specific class name `button-dingredient` to a button, how would you locate the button using JavaScript?

Comment: How are you generating your xpath? Are you using a browser extension like FirePath or Selenium IDE to generate the XPath? You should never have to inject class names (attributes which can be used multiple times on multiple elements) or ids (a unique attribute per element) into your elements. Also, if there are no classes or ids available to anchor on to, I would question how the page is even getting styled effectively. Are you sure that there are no attributes in any of the elements that you can latch onto in your selectors?

Answer (score 0):

If you find that you're repeating your locators (e.g. long xpaths) in your scripted code, that shows that there is a problem. You could inject a unique class name for each element and use that locator from then on; but your scripted code would still have to repeat the new locator (unique classname).

I'd recommend structuring your scripts using a [Page Object model](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects); that way, each locator would be defined just once. As long as the locator is defined only once, it doesn't matter whether it's a short class name or a long xpath; and it would make your scripts clearer to read.

Comment: Im not repeating locators. I just thought filling my page object with xpaths that long might be worsening my code smell, and I thought doing it the way I proposed above would clean it up a little. Just not sure if that's actually any better or not.